# Why the program lsusb don't find the shared library libusb-1.0.so.0?

Tags: linux, centos, libraries

Linux distribution : CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)
Kernel : 3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64

**The problem :**

```
# lsusb
lsusb: error while loading shared libraries: libusb-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

# ldd /usr/bin/lsusb
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd446e0000)
libusb-1.0.so.0 => not found
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3cb0b14000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055cb87a1b000)
```

**While :**

```
# ldconfig -p | grep libusb-1.0.so.0
        libusb-1.0.so.0 (libc6) => /lib/libusb-1.0.so.0

# ls -als /lib/libusb*
  0 lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    19 Sep 16 10:13 /lib/libusb-1.0.so.0 -> libusb-1.0.so.0.1.0
100 -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 98420 Nov  5  2016 /lib/libusb-1.0.so.0.1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the repective package is not installed. 
Check with # yum whatprovides libusb-1.0.so.0.

Most probably it will be solved by installing the below RPM:

```
# yum install libusb
```

Comment: Actually it's libusbx RPM:

rpm -ql libusbx
/usr/lib64/libusb-1.0.so.0
/usr/lib64/libusb-1.0.so.0.1.0
...

Comment: Arg yes only the 32-bit version of the library was installed. So I had to install the 64-bit version.

Answer (score 0):

the /lib directory might be ommited when looking for libraries.
Try to put the line

```
/lib
```

in **/etc/ld.so.conf**
and then run

```
ldconfig -v
```

See if that helps

Comment: ldconfig -p : Print the lists of directories and candidate libraries stored in the current cache.

Comment: it does, but I wanted to deliberately skip the cache to be sure that the file is really there and ldconfig can read it, that's why i suggested the verbose flag instead